# Sharepoint-hosted Add-In EditControlBlock select multiple files

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, ecb-menu

I can send only one file to my plugin: [image: Sharepoint plugin single selection menu] 
[image: Sharepoint plugin multiple selection menu]

**I want to send multiple files to my app. Is it possible?**

Here is how I add menu item to menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="4d31f35b-1af7-4c37-8c85-a2a45f29db52.MenuItemSendForSignature"
            RegistrationType="List"
            RegistrationId="101"
            Location="EditControlBlock"
            Sequence="10001"
            Title="Send to Plugin">
     <UrlAction Url="~appWebUrl/Pages/CheckStatus.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={ItemId}&amp;SPListId={ListId}" />
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```